# Partial overlap two background images in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I'm trying to overlap two images in CSS: the first one is a "background" image of the main menu and the second is the "cover" of the front page. The issue is that the first one is a png with transparency and it needs to display above the cover (right now, it doesn't goes beyond the div container).

Right now the result is this:

[image: Menu image]

But the first image, the one under ***#menu .container-fluid*** is this:

[image: Header image]

The current code:

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Content of menu -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portada">
        <figure class="proporcion-fija-indice"></figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.proporcion-fija-indice {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 48.30%; /* 2026px/4194px = 0.4830 */
  background-image: url('../img/portada.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#menu .container-fluid {
  background-image: url('../img/header.png');
  min-height: 125px;
}
```

Any ideas of how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You should use `z-index` for this. So  give a lower `z-index` for the item that has to be above the one with higher `z-index`.

Comment: @SupremeDEV z-index doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Note that `z-index` works only with posistioned elements. So `position: absolute/relative/etc`. Here are some examples  : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Ok. I've tried with position:relative in both elements and z-index as well, with a higher value in the first element and then backwards. But nothing changes.

Comment: I will try to make an anwser with plunker for you to show you how it works

Comment: @SupremeDEV Thanks for your help. The problem was solved with a combination of z-index and applying the negative margin-top, as suggested below.

Comment: perfect then. Good luck with your project. I have also prepared an example for you on how to make it work with positioning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the header higher, and setting a negative margin-top on proporcion-fija-indice?

```
.proporcion-fija-indice {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 48.30%; /* 2026px/4194px = 0.4830 */
  background-image: url('../img/portada.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-top:-50px;
}

#menu .container-fluid {
  background-image: url('../img/header.png');
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just tought about that and it was the solution. I've added `margin-top: -100px` in this case, as that solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index

```
#menu .container-fluid {
  background-image: url('../img/header.png');
  min-height: 125px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

another approach would be using position absolute in the #menu...this might need some adjustments..

Comment: z-index doesn't seem to work for neither of those elements, with positive or negative values alike.
position: absolute on the #menu breaks everything, even responsiveness, so that's a no go.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can make it work :

```css
#menu {
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRInk.png");
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
        background-repeat: no-repeat
}
#portada {
        background-image: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1500/1*d2MAPp7120q_8x6Ue8KYmQ.png");
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portada">
        <figure class="proporcion-fija-indice"></figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Really great example!

Comment: @Juank I'm glad to have been a help for you :)